# Python mysql create and name new table using variable name

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

So I have variable named 'racenumber' that I want to use as the name of a new table I'm creating.

The python code below is currently not working. Any ideas on where the issue is?

```
racenumber = 10

cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE %s (ID INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, NAME VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL,    
PRIZE_TOTAL VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL, STRENGTH VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL, URL VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT  
NULL ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1""" % (racenumber))

db.commit()
db.close()
```

Comment: do you want the table name to actually be 'racenumber' ??

Comment: nope it will be a variable thats changing dynamically.

Comment: no what I mean is do you want it to actually be the name of the variable? so for this case you want the table name to be 'racenumber'? or the value inside of it?

Comment: yep value inside, thanks for clarifying

Comment: then use backticks on the table name and u should be ok :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using a number for the table name, you need to use back-ticks around table name. I tested an example using SQL Fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c38e57

```
racenumber = 10

cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE `%s` (ID INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, NAME VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL,    
PRIZE_TOTAL VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL, STRENGTH VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL, URL VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT  
NULL ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1""" % (racenumber))

db.commit()
db.close()
```

Here is the link from documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html

Specifically this line:

> Identifiers may begin with a digit but unless quoted may not consist solely of digits